# OpenCL version constraints?

Tags: gpu, opencl

There's a computational code I'm working with which I'm told requires OpenCL 1.1 or later. I found out I'm saddled with OpenCL 1.0 on my Macbook Pro using some helpful [code snippets](http://dhruba.name/2012/08/13/opencl-cookbook-listing-all-platforms-and-their-attributes/), and Google has been remarkably opaque on how to update versions of OpenCL on OS X. The above code returns that my machine sports the following devices

> 1. Device: GeForce 9400M
>
>    1.1 Hardware version: OpenCL 1.0
>
>    1.2 Software version: CLH 1.0
>
>    1.4 Parallel compute units: 2
> 2. Device: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     P7550  @ 2.26GHz
>
>    2.1 Hardware version: OpenCL 1.0
>
>    2.2 Software version: 1.0
>
>    2.4 Parallel compute units: 2

Has anyone been able to either upgrade OpenCL for Mac, or can anyone explain what might limit (hardware, OS, etc) this computer from supporting OpenCL?

Thanks. Please let me know if there's a better place to post this; the connection to computational science seems a bit more tenuous with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GeForce 9400M video card is older and probably doesn't support the later OpenCL 1.1 spec.  Unfortunately, this is a hardware limitation that you can't fix with software- you'll need to get a newer computer if you want to run this software using OpenCL 1.1.

To be more specific, I believe that OpenCL 1.1 support is new in Mac OS X 10.7 but you also need compatible hardware and I don't think that the 9400M will cut it.